# AspNet Core - Dynamic razor views are not able to display the Values passed in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razorengine

I have this error when I try to render (using Razor) a View -that is stored in the database and compiled in runtime because I have Implemented a DataBaseFileProvider-

Before execure the dynamic view named ***7822946b-1234-4e6c-bde9-6646ed5f1e26*** :

I pass the ***variable***, but the Application always throws the famous and very known error   ***CS0103***

This is the segmented executed:

Im sure that I pass the value to the view.

```
public IActionResult MyProductionMethod(string jhon, string doe)
{
  ViewData.TryAdd("variable", new Dictionary<string,object>(){{"jhon","doe"}});
  return View("7822946b-1234-4e6c-bde9-6646ed5f1e26");
}
```

Im also Add this template as header in my 7822946b-1234-4e6c-bde9-6646ed5f1e26

```
{@Layout=null;}
```

This is the View provided by the DataBaseFileProvider -- with the undesired behavior.

```
@{  Layout=null; }
@{  
  var  foo = variableX["variable"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
} 

@variableX["jhon"]
```

The DataBaseFileProvider works fine because pages that DONT use ViewModel or PassedValues are being rendered by Razor.

This is the output, I See that in V2017 it was an Issue but V2019 has solved this Issue.

Do you have suggestions or tips to find root cause?

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
/Views/Task/7822946b-1234-4e6c-bde9-6646ed5f1e26 (1,123): error CS0103: The name 'variable' does not exist in the current context

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument, String generatedCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String relativePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(String normalizedPath)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(String relativePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet`1 expirationTokens, String relativePath, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromPath(String executingFilePath, String pagePath, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.GetView(String executingFilePath, String viewPath, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.GetView(String executingFilePath, String viewPath, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I have changed the names of the original name of the variables.

Comment: `The name variable does not exist in the current context` seems you didn't define the variable which name is `variable` in razor page.

Comment: As you can in the post the variable is defined; here: ViewData.TryAdd("variable", new Dictionary<string,object>(){{"jhon","doe"}}); the view data does have the name 'variable' as a know variable:Dictionary<,>